# Can't install OpenJDK 8 due to not having an installation candidate

Tags: java, linux, debian, failed-installation

I am on Debian 9 and am trying to install OpenJDK 8. When I enter the command `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`, however, I get an error saying `E: Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' has no installation candidate`. I have installed build-essential and git, but it still does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: JDK/JRE 8 is no longer supported on a lot of debian versions. I'm not sure about 9, but most likely the fastest way to fix this is jdk-11.

Comment: https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot#linux-pkg

Answer (score 1):

You can download by the following way :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

git has nothing to do with it. Your OS can't find a package containing openJDK 8. Try `apt-cache openjdk-8` to see if there are any known packages containing what you need.

If the `cache`command finds a package, use your favorite editor to add it to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and try installing again.

If `cache` cannot find what you want in a current package, search through old packages at http://snapshot.debian.org/.